# compare two dates with javascript extracted from HTML5 data

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, sorting

I have a array which needs to be sorted before displaying.
There is a code how I crate my array

```
    for ( $i = 0, $count = count( $notifications ); $i < $count; ++$i ) {
        $alt = ( 0 == $counter % 2 ) ? ' class="alt"' : ''; ?>
        <script>
        array[i] = '<li><?php echo addslashes($notifications[$i]);?></li>';
        i++;
        </script>
        <?php $counter++;
    }

?>
```

here is how each cycle looks like:

`<li><a data-date="2013-06-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">text!</a></li>`

now I need sort this array by data-date attribute.

This is how far I have gone, but without success.

```
var joint = array.join("<br/>");    
aka = jQuery(joint).find('a').sort(function (a, b) {
    return '<li>' +a.getAttribute('data-date') - +b.getAttribute('data-date') + '</li>';
})
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an actual JavaScript array to represent your data instead of DOM elements?

Comment: Creating a ton of `<script>` tags is a really bad idea. Why don't you create a nicely-formatted JSON string with PHP and pass it off to JavaScript?

Comment: this data comes from different functions. in wordpress $notifications are called like $notifications = bp_core_get_notifications_for_user( bp_loggedin_user_id() )

can I represent it in JS inside this script?
I was thinking doing something similar but stuck with multidimensional arrays .. where sorting would become much painfull

Comment: @Blender yeaah, I will rewrite it nicely in the end ))so I don't use <script> tags repeadtly. thanks

Comment: @Mpa4Hu I've posted a solution on how to re-order your List based on the data-date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions, these being one to use javascript and one to use PHP.

### **Pure Javascript Solution:**

Here is how to sort your `<li>` based on the data-date attribute.

I've included both date based and string based sorting.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xZaeu/

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<ul id="ulList">
<li><a data-date="2013-09-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">09!</a></li>
<li><a data-date="2013-08-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">08!</a></li>
<li><a data-date="2013-07-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">07!</a></li>
<li><a data-date="2013-11-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">11!</a></li>
<li><a data-date="2013-10-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">10!</a></li>
<li><a data-date="2013-06-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">06!</a></li>
</ul>

<script>

function compareDataDates(a,b)
{
    var match = a.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)$/);
    var date1 = new Date(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5], match[6]);

    match = b.match(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+)\:(\d+)\:(\d+)$/);
    var date2 = new Date(match[1], match[2] - 1, match[3], match[4], match[5], match[6])

    return date1 - date2;
}

var list = $('#ulList');
var listItems = list.find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
        return compareDataDates($(a).find('a').eq(0).attr("data-date"), $(b).find('a').eq(0).attr("data-date"));
        //return $(a).find('a').eq(0).attr("data-date").localeCompare($(b).find('a').eq(0).attr("data-date"));
    });
list.find('li').remove();
list.append(listItems);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Both String and date comparison work since your using the specific format, though the string based comparison would fail in a situation where you have:

```
<li><a data-date="2013-06-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">06!</a></li>
<li><a data-date="2013-6-16 11:44:50" href="http://example.com/url/">6!</a></li>
```

**References used cooking this up:**

- [How to order dynamically created elements based on a custom attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076820/how-to-order-dynamically-created-elements-based-on-a-custom-attribute)
- [Get all hrefs as an array in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471606/get-all-hrefs-as-an-array-in-jquery)
- [Optimum way to compare strings in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167602/optimum-way-to-compare-strings-in-javascript)
- [Compare dates with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170054/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)
- [How to convert date in format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" to UNIX timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704325/how-to-convert-date-in-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-to-unix-timestamp)
- [jquery find to get the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173971/jquery-find-to-get-the-first-element)

### **Pure PHP Solution:**

Something along the lines of...

```
   <?php
    //Other PHP code here...
   $arrayForSorting = new array();

   foreach ($notifications as &$value) 
   {
      $temp = addslashes($value);
      array_push($arrayForSorting,"<li>".$temp."</li>");  
   }

   //Sort the array
   asort($arrayForSorting);

   foreach ($arrayForSorting as &$value) 
   {
     echo $value;
   }

   ?>
```

**References:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: thanks, that did the trick, I used string based javascript solution.
final question, how to make it work in reverse ? )))

for now, it goes from oldest date and goes to current,
I want it to start from current

Comment: Just change the return to `return date2 - date1;`